# Extra content in Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to have a Fancybox effect that displays:

Image, Title, Paragraph

It only really displays the image and title.

How can I display some text in the overlay box too?

```
<li>
<a class="fancybox" rel="projects" href="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="" />
</a>
<p>Some content...</p>      
</li>

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding : 0,
        nextEffect : 'fade',
        prevEffect : 'fade',
        title : this.title,
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            }
        }
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `title` property of fancybox can be set to any valid HTML. It really behaves more like a caption than a proper title. So you can do something like:

```
    title = '<h1>' + this.title + '</h1><p>' + this.parent().children('p').html() + '</p>',
```

Then your fancybox will have a div of class `fancybox-title` that contains a `h1` element with your title in it and `p` element that is a copy of the paragraph in your `li`. The problem with my example is that `children` will return every paragraph element that is a child of the `li` element. So if you have more than one paragraph in your `li` it will try to grab them all. I would recommend restructuring the HTML so that you can potentially have multiple block-level elements in your fancybox caption. Enclose the paragraph in a div with a specific class and use that class as a selector in the `children` method so you can put multiple paragraphs in there or whatever you want really. If you have no need for multiple paragraphs, assign a class to the `p` tag and select on that in the `children` method.

```
    <li>
      <a class="fancybox" rel="projects" href="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="" />
      </a>
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Some content...</p>
      </div>      
    </li>

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding : 0,
        nextEffect : 'fade',
        prevEffect : 'fade',
        title : '<h1>' + this.title + '</h1>' + this.parent().children('.caption').html(),
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            }
        }
    });
```

You can replace the `h1` with whatever you feel is most appropriate of course. Add styles to your CSS file for the header and paragraph, and you're good to go (`.fancybox-title h1 {}` and `.fancybox-title p {}`).

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, you could just use `siblings()` instead of `parent().children()`. I'm used to using fancybox in more complex lists and `parent()` is just kind of a habit.